# Find what file types are registered by other applications

Tags: ios

I know how to register what file types my apps can handle (using `Info.plist`), but is there a way to find out what file types other apps have registered to handle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. This can't be done using normal, public APIs at runtime. Use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` to let users select an appropriate app for a given file you wish to share for your app.

You can always unzip the ipa file on your computer and look at the Info.plist but this can't be done on an iOS device.